# PyCharm environment vs Matlab environment?

Tags: python, matlab, pycharm, command-window

I am new to Python and PyCharm and I am having troubles using my Matlab knowledge here on PyCharm. The thing is that in Matlab you have:

1. Your script where you write your matlab code
2. Workplace where the results or variables are saved
3. Command Window where you call your function or you call your variables or do something more.

Now, I am trying to understand how I can do these things on PyCharm but I dont even understand where files are saved or how I can call a function without it being in the main file where I write down my code. My question is 
Is there something similar to a command window in PyCharm?

Comment: You may want to use Spyder

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent for command window is the **Python Console**, you can find it in the lower left side of Pycharm.

Comment: I am trying to use it but from what I can see, it is not possible to call the functions or variables that are calculated in the code (i.e. in the python file where I am writing my code).